# axis titles size changes when using patchwork r

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, patchwork

I have created the following plot.

[image]

As you can see, in the top bar chart, the y-axis title does not fit. However, in the original plot it is smaller and fits perfectly fine. This issue only pops up when I use patchwork library to place all the plots toguether. I do not underestand why the sizes of the axis change and I do not know how it could be solved. I have used patchwork as follows:

```
#arrange all plots together with patchwork library 

Y <- (A_ordered + legend + B_ordered + C_ordered) + 
  plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, heights = c(1, 3), widths = c(2.75, 1))
```

any ideas?? Thaaaanks!

Comment: Adjust your font sizes. When you plot your top plot in isolation it will be fitted into the whole canvas. However, when using patchwork it will be fitted into only a part of the canvas, e.g. according to your plot_layout your top plot will be fit into a canvas with only one fourth of the total height. What patchwork does not do for you is to adjust the font sizes. As a result your legend title gets cut off. It's up to you to take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation Stefan! Do you mean to adjust them in the isolated plot? Because I had tried to do so in the isolated plot but did not changed the result in the final assembly. Maybe I need to try even smaller sizes or maybe there is a function to do that with patchwork? I have seen cases where people use plot_annotation(tag_levels = ''), but that is used to add new titles in the assembled figure...  thanks again!

Comment: You could adjust the size of the legend titles for all plots at once by adding e.g. `&
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 6))` after plot_layout. Note the use of `&` instead of `+`.

Comment: That is even a better solution and I have tried it and worked out great! Thanks